# serializing separate address string into one in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, parsing, serialization

you may already know how to parse an address into separate sections such as unit number / street number / street name / town / state and etc...
Almost similar issue here. I want to serialize those separately entered data into one. For example, I have

```
Level /
Unit number /
Street number /
Street name /
Street type /
Town /
State /
Post code / Etc...
```

Let's say user entered

> blank / blank / 10 / Flinders / lane / blank / VIC / 3000

Then I would like to have the information in one string like

> 10 Flinders Lane VIC 3000

I'm currently doing this as the follow

```
if (level !== '' && level !== 0) {string = level + '/';}
if (unit !== '' && unit !== 0) {string += unit;}
if (streetNo !== '' && streetNo !== 0) {string += '/' + streetNo + ' ';} 
else {string += ' ';}
string += streetName + ' ' + streetType + ' ';
if (town !== '' && town !== '--' && town !== 0) {string += town + ' ';} 
else {string += ' ';}
string += state;
```

it is hard coded but I cannot come up with any better way. I would like to know if there is any better and efficient + professional way to achieve this.

Comment: Well, that code has an issue if `level` is `''` or `0`. All the rest of your conditions assume `string` will already be initialized. You need `string = "";` at the outset in case `level` doesn't set it.

Comment: I'm curious about `streetNo.g`. What is `streetNo`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  Oh sorry that was a typo.. it was part of my code that include unrecognizable var names haha. and yes I initialize the string var before the code. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the delimiters you want on the string seem to vary according to which part of the string they follow (some have `'/'`, others have `' '`), there's probably not a lot you can do there.

If the delimiter were always the same (such as a space), you *might* use an array and then use `join`:

```
var parts = [];
if (level      !== '' && level      !== 0)      parts.push(level);
if (unit       !== '' && unit       !== 0)      parts.push(unit);
if (streetNo.g !== '' && streetNo.g !== 0)      parts.push(streetNo.g);
if (streetName !== '' && streetName !== 0)      parts.push(streetName);
if (streetType !== '' && streetType !== 0)      parts.push(streetType);
if (town !== '' && town !== 0 && town !== '--') parts.push(town);
if (state      !== '' && state      !== 0)      parts.push(state);
string = parts.join(' ' );
```

Comment: Yep it seems like I don't have many options here. Thanks for the neat code. :)